# How to perform code analysis in sonarqube in docker in a ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, sonarqube

I have the official SonarQube docker image running successfully under http://localhost:32768/ (it is the one provided by Docker)

We want to perform some code analysys with C#.NET, this application is located in a folder called c:\myapplication (that is where I have the prj and sln)

My question is HOW! how can I tell my SonarCube, running in my docker http://localhost:32768/ , I want to analyse my C# code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but after a couple of hours, I decided to write a post in my blog in how to do it step by step.

I know that there is plenty of documentation, but there are many bits and pieces to touch before you can see the analysis done properly.

I decided to shared my views and result with you guys,

http://netsourcecode.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/continuous-code-quality-with-net.html

have fun!

Answer (score 5):

Since the second answer provided seemed to be windows specific I decided to write down how it can be done in Linux, including the sonarqube installation.

1.) Run the command:

```
$sudo docker pull sonarqube
```

This will pull the docker image.

2.) Run the server using the command:

```
$sudo docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube
```

This will run the sonarqube server.  You can then go to Firefox and visit the server at http://localhost:9000 and login with the password "admin" and user "admin.

------------------------------ Analyzing projects -------------------------------------------------------------------

1.) Download the sonarqube scanner from here:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

2.) Unzip and place the files in a folder.

3.) Give executable permissions to the sonarcube file as follows:

```
$chmod +x <path-to-extracted-folder>/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227/bin/sonar-scanner
```

4.) Create a project using the user interface in firefox (localhost:9000).

5.) Go to the directory where the sln file is at and run the project commands.  They will have one of the following forms:

```
$SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"project-key"
$MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
$SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

or

```
$dotnet <path to SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll> begin /k:"project-key"
$dotnet build
$dotnet <path to SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll> end
```

Either should work.  Afterward you can see the your results in firefox.

Answer (score 3):

To be pedantic about it, SonarQube doesn't analyze code. It presents the results of analyses to you (okay, it does actually do some further metric aggregation and calculation server-side). Instead, you want to tell the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild to analyze your code. [Doing so is fully documented](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).

Essentially

1. install the scanner
2. execute the Begin step (this tells the scanner to start listening)
3. (re)build your solution
4. execute the End step (tells the scanner to stop listening and process what it heard)
5. browse your project in the SonarQube interface.

The specific commands would look something like this:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

Comment: To be pedantic about it, this was actually a very helpful distinction.